# Rails + Stripe Amount Transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment

I am getting the following error while trying to transfer an amount from admin account to another user account in Stripe:

> Transfers to other Stripe accounts can only be made if you've
>   registered a Connect application. To do so, see
>   https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started.

But I have registered the application.

I am doing oauth to get authentication from admin and transferring the amount to another connected account.

```
 Stripe::Transfer.create(
 :amount => 1000,
 :currency => "usd",
 :destination => "acct_t64sGCKrnINZrjyc"
 )
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?